# How can I send a Twitter direct message from a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, twitter

I would like to send a direct message from the background page of my Google Chrome extension.

I read the twitter documentation but there does not seem to be an easy solution.

Did someone do this before? So far I've tried to send the message using a AJAX call with this API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/direct_messages/new  I have error 400.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json",
  data: {'text': 'Hello World', 'screen_name':'John'}
}).done(function( res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter REST API v1.1 requires authentication

There are a list of useful libraries [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) you can use

And [this is a really useful Twitter proxy script](http://mikerogers.io/2013/02/25/how-use-twitter-oauth-1-1-javascriptjquery.html), just replace the tokens and access keys with those of your application's and route all requests to it - however I haven't used this for POST requests